SSIS Package with 7-zip exe not working in SQL Server Agent
I created a SSIS package to extract zip files (which contains Csv files) using 7-zip  then uploads the data into SQL Server. When I run it in Visual Studio, it worked perfectly, but when I run the job in SQL Server Agent, I get this message:

The process exit code was "2" while the expected was "0"

I tried the following to resolve the issue but no luck:

Changed the SSIS 7-zip file location to: C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip
I placed the 7-zip exe folder in the location where my zip files are located.
I used the hyperlink where the 7-zip is located
I used the mapped drive link where the 7-zip is located
I am logged in as an admin (both SSMS and SSIS) so permission is not an issue.

For item #3 above - the job says it was successful but it didn't extract the zip files.
SSIS Execute Process Task
Executable: Z:\ZIP_Files\7-Zip\7z.exe or \\nas\PIND\VAULTSAMPLES\datasamples01\Medina OH\Recorder Data\Historical\ZIP_Files\7-Zip\7z.exe (I tried both)
Arguments: E "\\nas\PIND\VAULTSAMPLES\datasamples01\Medina OH\Recorder Data\Historical\ZIP_Files" -y
Working Directory: \\nas\PIND\VAULTSAMPLES\datasamples01\Medina OH\Recorder Data\Historical\ZIP_Extraction

When the exit code is 2, does it extract the files as expected? I would advise against mapped drives (unless you need to mount the drive as a different user from the one executing the SSIS package) as it can difficult to ensure you have a consistent environment established.  I assume the Arguments align with the Arguments section in an SSIS Execute Process Task? For debugging purposes, what if you add a precursor step to your existing sql agent job, of type Operating system and then try your commands. Is there any difference? Capture task output to the job and maybe you'll get a better error.

No, It didn't extract the files at all.  What do you mean by adding precursor step to my agent job?

https://i.sstatic.net/C292L.png  Insert a step before the existing SSIS job step in your job and on the Advanced tab, add Include step output in history https://i.sstatic.net/qIqip.png

try running against some local file, preferably in 7z folder and see if that works
